# Eclipse loads but gives an error "initializing java tooling"

Tags: eclipse

I have been running eclipse properly.  After it loads I get:
"Initializing Java Tooling".
Incompatible magic value 0 in class file org/eclipse/jdt/internal/core/search/BasicSearchEngine

I have been looking, and what I have found is Eclipse hanging initializing java tooling

I have set JAVA_HOME and -vm in eclipse.ini

Still, no success.

Any ideas would be appreciated

=======
Added after I solved the issue
(Stack Overflow won't let me post this as an answer cause I am of ill repute.)

Never mind.

It may be important to have the answer to what I did so that people that have the same issue does not have to go through the hoops I went.

First, I went to the Help/About Eclipse/Installation Details. In the Installation History, with using compare and revert, I started reverting what I had installed (Compare and Revert are pretty cool BTW.) I finally detected which was the latest stable version, and the installation that broke it all

Spring Source at http://dist.springsource.com/release/TOOLS/update/e3.7

Initially I selected some extra components that sounded cool, but the second time around I pretty much went for the required, plus support for AOP, Web Tools, and Flex and WebServices. Other than that I ignored all the rest of the stuff. That worked.

I had selected before (one of the ones that killed it, do not exactly which one), in addition to what I left installed: Spring Mylyn Integration Spring Tool Suite AWS Integration Spring Tool Suite Maven Support Eclipse Weaving Source

I also had the "Mylyn Builds Connector: Jenkins/Hudson integration", which had worked for me in the past. I still suspect that it was one of the Spring components.

I hope this helps

Comment: I also have this issue occasionally. What usually works for me is to close all open files (i.e. files open in an editor, you don't have to close projects) in Eclipse and restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, a restart will solve this issue. As @Carsten mentioned, close all open files and terminate eclipse then re-launch the application. I have encountered this problem many times. The causes of this range from:

1. Low memory assigned to eclipse. You could increase the memory by editing the eclipse.ini file and change the options -X* JAVA_OPTS
2. Loading large files (XML is always a culprit in this case).
3. Attempting to format large XML files
4. Immediately after installing a new plugin and not restarting eclipse right away
   etc

Answer (score 1):

Clean \Workspaces\MyEclipse 8.5 M2.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.projects folder after closing eclipse/myeclipse .That's it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an STS issue however they blame it on an Eclipse bug which has been fixed:
https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-696. If you look at the dependencies of the STS plugin you will notice that the Eclipse WTP version is way passed the one that is mentioned in the Eclipse Bug..